# How to plot loss, val_loss as well as accuracy, val_accuracy without using history when I fit the model

Tags: keras

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=mini_batch_size, epochs=nb_epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

plt.title('Accuracy')
plt.plot(model['accuracy'], label='train')
plt.plot(model['val_accuracy'], label='test')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

*ypeError: 'Functional' object is not subscriptable*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are some other alternatives:

1. [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard): Provides tools for visualizing, debugging, and understanding your models in the browser. take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/tensorboard-tutorial.html).
   [image]
2. [BaseLogger Class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/BaseLogger): You can code some model monitoring with this class. there is an example [here](https://github.com/agoila/lisa-faster-R-CNN/blob/master/pyimagesearch/callbacks/trainingmonitor.py).
3. [History Class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/History):  the callback that is used for keras models automatically and is actually that object that fit method returns.